# Keep running NSTimer switching Background and Foreground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background, nstimer

I am trying to create a NSTimer which is started *manually* by the user in foreground, and as expected works perfectly:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

where `updateCounter()` simply updates a `UILabel` in the UI.
Now what I want to achieve is to get it running also when the user leaves the application. I googled something and found this code (which I translated in Swift):

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
            var bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier()
            bgTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler { () -> Void in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
            }
            // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in



               var vc = TimerViewController()
               // Fire some methods
               UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
               bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
               });
        }
```

Basically from what I can understand here is that when app reaches background I can fire some methods from a new instance of my `TimerViewController()`, which is supposed to handle the `NSTimer` for the background phase.

Now does this imply that I need to use a method from this vc, or another, which starts another `NSTimer` starting from the exact time in which the foreground-one was stopped (because app entered background)?

If yes, to resume my first `NSTimer` when the user opens the app again (meaning foreground again :D) how should I behave? Stop the second `NSTimer` and resume the first with updated counter?

Actually even a sketch of the solution is appreciated, I'm just trying to figure out how to handle the situation.

**further question**: If what it's written above turn out to be correct how can I manage the instances of the `viewcontroller` to get the `timer_value`(token for something like `secondsLeft`) when a switch from background to foreground or vice-versa happens?

Comment: Did you try to use [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:loop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to maintain an `NSTimer` in the background (which is impossible beyond about 10 minutes), what you want to do is record when your timer started and save that in `NSUserDefaults`. You can still update your timer every second, but just recalculate the label based on the start time (remember, `NSTimer` doesn't promise that it will run on time; it could be late for many reasons and you'll drift).

Now there is no reason to run in the background. When your view controller comes onscreen (`viewDidAppear:`), just update the label again, based on the start time saved in `NSUserDefaults`.

There is no way in iOS to run indefinitely in the background. That's by design. But there's also no reason for you to be wasting system resources trying to update your UI when you're not onscreen. Just update it when you are.

Comment: This approach has many advantages, especially if you are writing a timer or stopwatch type application.  You can easily use this pattern to make your "timer" persist even across a device reboot.  If you're trying to accomplish a count down timer, consider using a UILocalNotification to fire when the time expires.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's pretty clear! Now if I want a countdown of 30 minutes and send a notification to the user as @JeremyPope said I have to use UILocalNotification right? But how is the timer handled in this case?

Comment: The only use for the `NSTimer` is while your view is on the screen. The `UILocalNotification` is only really needed while you're in the background. So they handle separate situations.

Comment: The local notification could be used to notify the user that their timer expired, even though they are in another application.